# Continuous functions from compact Hausdorff spaces to the interval

Tags: general-topology, compactness, function-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $C(X,I)$ be the set of all continuous functions from $X$ into the closed interval $[0,1]$. If we equip $C(X,I)$ with the the topology of uniform convergence is $C(X,I)$ compact? I'm inclined to think not, but I can't think of a simple counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C(X,I)$ is the closed ball of radius $1/2$ centred at the constant function $1/2$ in the Banach space $C(X,\mathbb R)$.  A closed ball of nonzero radius in a Banach space is compact if and only if the Banach space is finite-dimensional.  $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is infinite-dimensional.  Therefore $C(X,I)$ is not compact.

Comment: Ahh, forgot to think about banach spaces. Thank you.